# Figure disappearing across right margin

Tags: floats, alignment

MWE:

```
\documentclass{informs3}

\usepackage{natbib,url}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
 \bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{,}%
 \def\bibfont{\small}%
 \def\bibsep{\smallskipamount}%
 \def\bibhang{24pt}%
 \def\newblock{\ }%
 \def\BIBand{and}%

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{VBLoutputNorth1.pdf}
    \label{fig_outputNorth}
  \end{sidewaysfigure}
  \caption{North Division Team}
```

I have never had so much trouble with a figure before. It seems that no matter what I do, the figure is determined to stayright where it is on the margin, running over regardless of how I try to push it to the middle. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: `width=\textheight`  or `height=\textwidth` will possibly fix the problem .... sideways figure doesn't change `\textwidth` and `\textheight`

Comment: Tried both: 'width=\textheight' did nothing different and 'height=\textwidth' made the image bigger and brought it closer to the center, but it's still sticky at the same place (the line for 9th of June 'height=\textwidth'

Comment: Have you checked the image to see if it contains empty space below of it? May be my comment above is not correct since I had in mind `landscape` environment and not the `sidewaysfigure` initially

Comment: There originally was, but I cut it out of the pdf. I think @gernot's answer below is going to work out! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try it this way (note also the order of `\caption`, `\label`, and `\end{figure}`.

```
\documentclass{informs3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{sideways}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \end{sideways}
  \caption{North Division Team}
  \label{fig_outputNorth}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is almost perfect... turns out I was missing the graphicx package. The only other hangup is that (as I'm still relatively new to LaTex) how to adjust the size so that it's a bit more readable on the page. But I think I can go hunt down some resources to explain the width=\textwidth thing :) Thanks again!

Comment: @Allison The option `width=\textwidth` tells the image importing command to scale the width of the image to `\textwidth` which is a length set to the width of the text. As it may be confusing what LaTeX considers as width/height in a rotated image, and the caption needs some space too, I suggest to experiment alternatively either with `width=8cm` or `height=10cm` (modify the values and units) such that the image fits on the page without generating an `overfull \hbox` or `overfull \vbox`  warning. If you use `height` and `width`, then the image may not be scaled proportionally.